# Existing Facebook API permissions not working

Tags: ios, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, posting

As of last Saturday we started having problems with our Facebook API permissions on an existing app, which allows the user to upload photos taken through our app to their personal Facebook pages. A message appeared on the Login permissions screen that said our app may break after April 30, 2015, and that some permissions below have not been approved for use by Facebook. But it still allowed the user to post a photo to their page. However the next time someone logged into Facebook to upload a photo [taken through our app] the login screen said 'This does not let the app post to Facebook', and the photo did not appear. Since then we have also had the odd instance where another screen appears, which says the app will break after April 30, 2015 but it does not let the photo upload.  We are in the process of updating the code for the updated FB API permissions, however as this takes time, we would appreciate any assistance anyone can offer to help us get our current permissions working again in the interim. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the api v1.0 it will available until April 30, 2015 .. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

My advice to you is to update your app and use and read the latest version of facebook api because there are lot of changes.